# Inserting and item into CComboBoxEx and ReleaseBuffer

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, comboboxex

Code:

```
m_cbReminderInterval.ResetContent();
for (int i = 1; i <= m_iMaxReminderInterval; i++)
{
    COMBOBOXEXITEM cmbItem = {};
    CString strNumber;
    strNumber.Format(_T("%d"), i);

    cmbItem.mask = CBEIF_TEXT;
    cmbItem.iItem = static_cast<INT_PTR>(i) - 1;
    cmbItem.pszText = strNumber.GetBuffer(_MAX_PATH);
    strNumber.ReleaseBuffer(); // TODO: When should I release the buffer - NOW or AFTER the InsertItem call?

    m_cbReminderInterval.InsertItem(&cmbItem);
}
```

My question is:

*Is it better to use `GetString` instead of `GetBuffer` in this context? The only issue I see is that `pszText` is `LPWSTR` whereas `GetString` returns `LPCWSTR`. If I should continue to use `GetBuffer` then when should it actually be released? Before or after the `InsertItem` call?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a common pattern in the Windows API you'll see over and over again: Structures that are less `const`-correct than what would appear to be possible. Undoubtedly, some of them are oversights, but not this one: [`COMBOBOXEXITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-comboboxexitemw) is used both to insert and query an item's data.

This is hinted to, in part, in the documentation for the `pszText` member:

> A pointer to a character buffer that **contains or receives** the item's text. If text information is being retrieved, this member must be set to the address of a character buffer that will receive the text.

The second part of the contract is omitted from the documentation, sadly. When setting an item's text, the control makes a copy of the string passed in, and neither takes ownership over the pointed to data, nor modifies it. In other words: When using the `COMBOBOXEXITEM` structure to insert an item, all pointers can be assumed to point to `const`.

Following that, it is perfectly valid to pass the pointer received from [`GetString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class#getstring):

```cpp
for (int i = 1; i <= m_iMaxReminderInterval; i++)
{
    COMBOBOXEXITEM cmbItem = {};
    CString strNumber;
    strNumber.Format(_T("%d"), i);

    cmbItem.mask = CBEIF_TEXT;
    cmbItem.iItem = static_cast<INT_PTR>(i) - 1;
    cmbItem.pszText = const_cast<TCHAR*>(strNumber.GetString());

    m_cbReminderInterval.InsertItem(&cmbItem);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer too and clarifications. One question ... In the underlying structure the member variable is designed as `LPWSTR pszText`. Should I be using `LPWSTR` as the casting type? Since I use this code to build for 32 bit and 64 bit.

Comment: That's not entirely correct. `COMBOBOXEXITEM` does not actually exist. It maps to either the `W` or `A` variant, depending on whether the `UNICODE` preprocessor symbol is defined. Likewise, `CString` does not actually exist. It maps to either `CStringA` or `CStringW`, depending on some more complex preprocessor symbol evaluation. Since you are using the generic-text mapping for either type, the `TCHAR*` is the correct, compatible type. Personally, I'd use `CStringW` and `COMBOBOXEXITEMW`, with the corresponding string type `wchar_t*`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [`CSimpleStringT::GetBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class?view=msvc-160#getbuffer):

> If you use the pointer returned by `GetBuffer` to change the string contents, you must call `ReleaseBuffer` before you use any other `CSimpleStringT` member methods.

You are not modifying the string, so you don't need to call `ReleaseBuffer`.

But as you said, it's better to use `GetString`, at least you indicate your intent to NOT modify it.

Comment: Thanks. So it should be acceptable to simply use: `cmbItem.pszText = strNumber.GetString();` and remove the `strNumber.ReleaseBuffer()`. I will try.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle be aware that `ReleaseBuffer` is only to be called aftr `GetBuffer`. `GetString` just gives you the pointer to the CString's buffer, that's all.